# Cannot Load Training Samples to Edit?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, image-classification

I'm trying to do a maximum likelihood classification with supervised training samples. I saved the training samples as a .gsg and I was able to load it into a maximum likelihood classification and successfully run the tool.

I want to load the old training samples back into the training sample manager so that I can improve the accuracy, but every time I hit load training samples the folder is blank.

I'm confused because I was able to load it into the tool, but I can't seem to load them in through the training sample manager. Is there a specific way I should save it or open it?

I've attached an image of my screen the GSG appearing as I load it into the geoprocessing tool.

[image: I've attached an image of my screen the GSG appearing as I load it into the geoprocessing tool.]